# Demonstrate a inequality of binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim B(n;\;p)$ and $\hat{p}=\frac{X}{n}$. I have to demonstrate that $Var(\hat{p}) \le \frac{1}{4}n$.

---

I started like,
$$Var(\hat{p})=Var\left(\frac{X}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}Var(X)=\frac{1}{n}\left(np(1-p)\right)=p(1-p)$$

What can I continue the proof?

Comment: Variance is not linear. Should the bound be $(4n)^{-1}$ perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: as WimC noted, when you pull the $\frac{1}{n}$ out of the variance, it should become a $\frac{1}{n^2}$.  Note that $p(1 - p)$ achieves its maximum at $p = \frac{1}{2}$; thus $p(1 - p) \leq \frac{1}{4}$.  Putting it together, $$ \text{Var}(\hat{p}) = \frac{1}{n}p(1 - p) \leq \frac{1}{4n}. $$

Comment: See my comment to OP.

Comment: @WimC, Ah, you're right. $\frac{1}{4n}$ would make more sense.

Comment: @WimC Can you remember me why we have to power up the $n$ when we pull out the constant out of the variance?

Comment: @hlapointe,  $\text{Var}(cX) = \mathbb{E}((cX)^2) - (\mathbb{E}(cX))^2 = \mathbb{E}(c^2 X^2) - c^2 (\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = c^2 \mathbb{E}(X^2) - c^2 (\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = c^2 \text{Var}(X)$.